# How do I make the title of the following widget editable?

Tags: widgets

I have the following widget which displays basic info for a game:

```
class Game_Info_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
                'game_info_widget', // Base ID
                'Game - Info', // Name
                array('description' => __('Game - Info', 'text_domain'),) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget($args, $instance) {

        if (!is_singular('games')) {
            return;
        }

        extract($args);
        $title = 'Game Info'; //apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;
        //if ( ! empty( $title ) )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        //echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );


        $templates = array();

        $templates[] = "game-info.php";


        // Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
        locate_template($templates, true);

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form($instance) {
        /*
          if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
          $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
          }
          else {
          $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
          }
         */
        ?>
        This widget only show on Game single page
        <?php
        /*
          ?>
          <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
          <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
          </p>
          <?php
         */
    }

}
```

The problem is that the title of the widget is not editable. How do I do that?

Comment: you try with that
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
          <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />

Comment: @ Yatendra Where should I put that? In `functions.php` or in the template where I'm using my widget?

Comment: in your code 
in  public function form($instance)
only need to remove comments

Comment: @Yatendra please add that as a constructive answer, don't post code in comments, it is unreadable

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
 <?php


    class Game_Info_Widget extends WP_Widget {

        /**
         * Register widget with WordPress.
         */
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
                    'game_info_widget', // Base ID
                    'Game - Info', // Name
                    array('description' => __('Game - Info', 'text_domain'),) // Args
            );
        }

        /**
         * Front-end display of widget.
         *
         * @see WP_Widget::widget()
         *
         * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
         * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
         */
        public function widget($args, $instance) {

            if (!is_singular('games')) {
                return;
            }

            extract($args);
            $title = $instance['title']; 
        //apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

            echo $before_widget;
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            //echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );


            $templates = array();

            $templates[] = "game-info.php";


            // Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
            locate_template($templates, true);

            echo $after_widget;
        }

        /**
         * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
         *
         * @see WP_Widget::update()
         *
         * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
         * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
         *
         * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
         */
        public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);

            return $instance;
        }

        /**
         * Back-end widget form.
         *
         * @see WP_Widget::form()
         *
         * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
         */
        public function form($instance) {

              if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
              $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
              }
              else {
              $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
              }


              ?>
              <p>
              <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
              <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
              </p>
              <?php

        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't just dump code. A constructive answer should have an explanation to how the code works and how it should be used. Please file an [edit] with all the relevant info and explanation

Comment: @Yatendra Hey, thanks it works. But the title doesn't change in the template: `<?php
echo get_field('info');
?>` Do I have to make any changes there?

Comment: I updated the code please check
USE THIS IN VALUE "<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>"